# How do I prevent jQuery $.ajax from adding a leading ampersand to the query string in the request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm trying to avoid handling this improperly encoded request on the server. I have a request with a single parameter like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://someplace.ontheinternets/count?",
    data: {
        days_since_epoch: 15460
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something with data
    }
});
```

This is giving me: http://someplace.ontheinternets/count?&days_since_epoch=15460

The leading ampersand is giving me problems on the other end (interpreted as two parameters with the first one being empty). Seems like an easy fix, but I did not see this specific issue in the related questions. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you add the ? in the first place?

Comment: as m90 pointed out it is useless jQuery will add it if needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put the `?` on it in your `url` parameter. Since you have it there, jQuery thinks the URL already has other parameters, and so adds the ones you asked it to add using an `&`. If you remove the `?` from the end of your `url` parameter, jQuery won't be fooled and will (for a single parameter) just use `?`.